# Line Feed in Autopilot Actions JSON

Tags: twilio

I am pulling actions from a URL using the autopilot RESTApi and would like to format the output as a list. How do I insert line feeds in the actions JSON to effect a change in the output format?

I've tried `\n` but that didn't work.

```
{
    "show": {
    "body": "First line\nSecond line"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dan. Did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @RedgrenGrumbholdt For the simulator, I did not find a solution. Newlines tend to work in actual sms though.

Comment: Oh, ok. So the issue is with the simulator, linked Messenger and the line breaks seemed to work also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

When you're using the RESTApi you may have to [use a different encoding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181468-How-do-I-Add-a-Line-Break-in-my-SMS-or-MMS-Message-).

Have you tried `%0a` for a line break?

Comment: That doesn't work either; it's explicitly included in the output.

Comment: Newlines work in actual sms; I should have tested it with actual sms, not just the simulator. Thanks!